# Is there a way I can add actions to NotNow button of UIAlertController and get it triggered after 24 hours if the user chooses that option?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift5

```
if !force {
    let notNowButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Not Now", style: .cancel) { action in  
        // Not getting what can be written here to make it trigger after 24 hours with the Logic
    }             
    alertController.addAction(notNowButton) 
}
```

I have written this func in a class which I am calling in AppDelegate class didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions function. The issue I am facing is the alert reappears every time the app is launched wanted it to not appear for 24 hours at least when this option is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the following in your ViewController, see the explanations in the comments.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        displayAlert()
    }


    
    func displayAlert() {
        // get previously stored date from some persistent store (UserDefaults is appropriate)
        let alertDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "alertDate")

        // was a date set previously?
        if let alertDate = alertDate as? Date,
            // add the desired time interval to get next possible alert date
            let nextPossibleAlertDate =  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: alertDate),
            // check if we're past that date
            nextPossibleAlertDate > Date() {
            print("too soon to bother again")
            return
        }

        // let's present the alert
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Do the annoying thing now?", message:
            nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Not now!", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
            // store the date when this happens
            let date = Date()
            print(date)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(date, forKey: "alertDate" )
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Date().addingTimeInterval(-1 * 24 * 60 * 60)` not everyday has 24h. Btw don't use `value(forKey)`. The proper method is `object(forKey)`. `if let alertDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "alertDate") as? Date {`

Comment: @LeoDabus – changed according to your suggestions.

Comment: @Ankit if I answered your question I’d appreciate if you would accept my answer with the green button!